# histogram with error bar in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

I want to put error bar in bar plot (above each bar). I tried

```
bincentres = -85:10:85;
nelements = [1,4,14,24,46,57,63,63,174,147,69,49,22,9,4,2,1,0];
err = sqrt(nelements);
bar(bincentres, nelements);
hold on
errorbar(bincentres,nelements, err);
hold off
```

Previously I was not getting errorbar because I was missing 'bincentres' in 'errorbar' in above code. Thanks to @Shai for pointing out that. But apart from error bar, now I get a line joining middle of each error bar. I want to skip that blue line.

Comment: Use `errobar` with a linespec that specifies no line. E.g. `errorbar(bincenters, nelements, err, '.')`. Check `doc linespec` if you'd like any other marker than the simple dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
errorbar( bincenters, nelements, err );
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It puts the error bar exactly above bar which I want. However, it also joins the middle of each error bar with a line. Is it possible to skip that line.

Comment: @raj it is very unclear what you want using these descriptions. Can you please post the results you are currently getting, and a more clear description of what you actually want?

Comment: thanks for nice comment. I edited my question for clarity. However, I don't know how to include figure here.

Comment: @raj I believe you need a certain reputation to upload images directly to your question. But you can always host an image on a web service (e.g. [imgur](http://imgur.com/)) ans then post a link to that picture in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the solution to what I exactly want. In the solution suggested by @Shai, I add 'bx' i.e., I modified it to

```
errorbar( bincenters, nelements, err,'bx' );
```

Thanks a lot to @Shai.