# How to add error bars to histogram in matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

I need to help adding error bars to my histogram. I calculate the errors once the histogram plotted (poission statistics - sqrt(N) of each bin, so I wasn't sure how to add them on!)

This is what I have so far:

```
rng('shuffle')
x=rand(1000, 1)
h=histogram(x, 20); % bin no = 20
hvalues=h.Values;  % this gives you the counts of each bar in histogram
h_error = sqrt(hvalues);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810513) not solve your problem? Another option is [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/bar-chart-with-error-bars.html).

Comment: Not really as I make the first histogram and then get the errors based on the counts in each bin. In those examples the errors are pre-defined.

Comment: Well, then perhaps you should use `histcounts` instead of doing the plot (using `histogram`), and only plot after you know all values? This is roughly equivalent to ignoring the first histogram you plotted and just make another one once the error bar values are known (according to the links I provided earlier).